# Wicket slide panel/div/x

Tags: java, javascript, animation, wicket

I'm creating my first wicket application and want to add some eyecandy stuff on this. I've got a panel which should be hidden until a link/button is clicked this should fire a slide animation and display the panel.

In `jQuery` this would be an easy: `$.slideToggle()` is there something built in for wicket components?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use an AjaxFallbackLink. 
To make the panel appear, you should override the onClick method. something like this

```
WebMarkupContainer hiddenPanel = // create your panel
hiddenPanel.setOutMarkupPlaceHolderTag(true);
hiddenPanel.setVisible(false)
...
AjaxFallbackLink myLink = new AjaxFallbackLink ("myLink") {

  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    hiddenPanel.setVisible(true);
    target.addComponent(hiddenPanel);
  }
};
```

That's the basics of it. When you click on the link, your onClick method is called and the hiddenPanel gets rendered in the web page.

Code edited after comments. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks for your answer. I know how to handle a partial reload but I want to add some animations to this effect

Comment: To do this, you need Javascript. The onClick event handler for the link should call a Javascript method to animate your panel (using slideToggle()). I've edited my answer above to give you the general idea

Comment: Thanks for this Andrew. I thought something like this would be included. So, I'll need to write javascript.

Comment: This answer is very wrong! 1) You can't just create the component in onClick(). It must be already added in the component tree, be invisible and having .setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true). 2) Adding AttributeAppender to an Ajax(Fallback)Link will override it's onclick attribute. Instead you should use AjaxLink.getAjaxCallDecorator().

Comment: well I did say I hadn't tested it. But I'm pretty sure I've used the AttributeAppender technique in the past to add a Javascript call to a link.